# Подключить меню к QWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Есть ли способ подключить меню к QWidget?
Например, мой код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow, QPushButton, 
QMessageBox, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(50, 50)

        qbtn = QPushButton('Exit', self)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50,100)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('My App')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))
        

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self,'Message',"Are you sure want to exit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = Example()
    ex.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Там, где `class Example(QWidget)`
И нужно, например, объединить кнопки и статус бар
Примерно так:

```
class Example(QWidget, QMainWindow):

    #                      ^^ ^^ ^^ ^^
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

        # ^^^

        btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(50, 50)

        qbtn = QPushButton('Exit', self)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50,100)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('My App')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))
        self.show()
```

Comment: Вот так нельзя делать: `class Example(QWidget, QMainWindow)` - Qt прямо говорит, что нельзя использовать множественное наследование от двух `QObject`-ов. Достаточно будет `class Example(QMainWindow)`, так как `QMainWindow` уже наследует `QWidget`.

Answer (score 1):

Самый удобный способ размещения на `QWidget` меню – использование у компоновщика метода `setMenuBar`.

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/4f7ed75bf3d9b2c4f4ffa04aceac2bb2a3f44ecc/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/QWidget_with_QMenuBar.py):

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class MainWindow(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        menu_bar = Qt.QMenuBar()
        menu_file = menu_bar.addMenu('File')
        action_exit = menu_file.addAction('Exit')
        action_exit.triggered.connect(self.close)

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(Qt.QLabel('Test'))
        layout.addWidget(Qt.QPushButton('Click!'))

        layout.setMenuBar(menu_bar)

        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]